# Find a point from the area tha is closest to the other point.

Tags: matrices, optimization

Given:
$$A=\{\left(x,y,z \right)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : 2x-3y+z=1 \}$$
Find a point $\left(x,y,z\right)\in A$ that is closest to $\left(3,-2,1 \right)$.
I do not know how to solve that problem, i need a solution that would involve use of hessian matrix. Other solutions are not acceptable. I know i need to minimize something but what should i minimize in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set $A \equiv 2x - 3y +z =1$ is a plane. So the point $Q \in A$ which is at the closest distance to $P=(3,-2,1)$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ on $A$.

The vector $\vec{v}=(2,-3,1)$ is orthogonal to $A$. So the line defined by the parametric coordinates $D \equiv (2 \lambda + 3, -3 \lambda -2, \lambda + 1)$ is passing through $P$ and is orthogonal to $A$. It intersect the plane $A$ for $$\lambda = -\frac{6}{7}$$ at point $$Q=(\frac{9}{7},\frac{4}{7},\frac{1}{7})$$

**Hint for a solution using minimization:**

- Define parametric coordinates for the plane $A$. A point $M \in A$ will be written $M(\alpha,\beta)$.
- You need then to minimize the function $$f(\alpha,\beta)=\Vert PM(\alpha,\beta) \Vert^2$$
- For this, find the point for which the derivative of $f$ vanishes... you should get $Q$!
- Look at the Hessian to prove that you have a minimum.

Comment: Nice solution, but any ideas when it comes to hessian matrix? Could be just a sketch of a solution.

Comment: I updated my answer in that direction.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help.